# "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done." connecting to Azure managed instance

Tags: azure, entity-framework, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

Connecting to an Azure Managed instance through Active Directory using the below connection string:

```
Server=tcp:server.address.database.windows.net,1433;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;Database=MyDB;Application Name=MyApp;
```

returns an error

```
No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
```

Connecting via server admin:

```
Server=tcp:server.address.database.windows.net,1433;User ID=someUser;Password=somePass;Database=MyDB;Application Name=MyApp;
```

works absolutely fine.

I have:

1. checked all listed users with AD authentication in the DB exist in AD
2. Started a trace for all calls to the server. Nothing is hitting it.
3. Started a log for the server. Nothing is hitting it.
4. Run the MS Azure diagnostic. Nothing is hitting the server.

Can anyone point me in a more sensible direction?

Comment: Test with "Active Directory Password" or, if MFA is required "Active Directory Interactive" to rule out AD->AAD mapping issues.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Tested with "Password" and is working just fine, but Integrated is required

Answer (score 2):

•   According to the error that you are receiving, you should first check your Azure AD federation with on premises Active Directory that is configured for seamless single sign-on for pass-through or password hash authentication.

•   Also, the system should be a domain joined one through which you are connecting to the managed instance logged in with the domain user.

•   Check the NSG for inbound connections on port 1433 as you are using in your connection string. Also, check the synchronization happening through Azure AD Connect in the Azure portal.

•   Lastly, please check whether the domain user through which you are logged in to the domain system has a role defined in the managed instance in Azure for its deployment environment that contains the user groups assigned to that managed instance and whether the User ID is valid or not.

Please refer the below link for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview

Thanking you,